# reply to a twitter direct message with python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to write a program that will reply to a user who sends a specific direct message.  I am very new to python, so any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  thanks a bunch, here's my code:

```
from twitter import *
import time

#Sets up twitter library
from twitter import * 
access_token = 'replaced'
access_token_secret = 'with'
consumer_key = 'this'
consumer_secret = 'stuff'

twitter_api = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))
twitter_userstream = TwitterStream( domain='userstream.twitter.com')
for msg in twitter_userstream.user():
    if 'weather' in msg:
        twitter_api.direct_messages.new(user=user, text='here is your current weather update.')
    else:
        twitter_api.direct_messages.new(user=user, text="That is not an acceptable request, try entering 'weather.'")
```

And here is the 401 error it came up with:

```
for msg in twitter_userstream.user():
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/twitter/api.py", line 312, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/twitter/stream.py", line 284, in _handle_response
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/twitter/stream.py", line 209, in handle_stream_response
twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 401 for URL: 1.1/user.json using parameters: (None)
details: <html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/user.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll just point out here, since this is high on Google results, that this repo is not being updated to work with Twitter API changes regarding DMs: https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/issues/382

Answer (score 0):

Please see Twython library here https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython

and here: https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

for a possible solution.